# The math behind generating Dungeons & Dragons ability scores: roll 4d6, toss lowest

Tags: probability, dice

D&D 5th ed. gives the following instructions for determining your “ability scores.”

> Roll four 6-sided dice and record the total of the highest three dice

If I repeat the “roll-toss-and-total” 6 times (generating a set of 6 totals), what is the probability that my resulting set will contain

- 4 or more totals ≥ 10 and
- 3 or more totals ≥ 12 and
- 2 or more totals ≥ 15?

*Note that this problem contains **and** statements.*

I already figured out the probabilities the totals of these rolls. (3: 1/1296;  4: 1/324;  5: 5/648;  6: 7/432;  7: 19/648;  8: 31/648;  9: 91/1296;  10: 61/648;  11: 37/324;  12: 167/1296;  13: 43/324;  14: 10/81;  15: 131/1296;  16: 47/648;  17: 1/24;  18: 7/432)

I can’t remember how to use these probabilities to ask more than basic questions. :-/

Answer (score 1):

For something with this many rules you would likely need to  manually add up the probabilities that satisfy your conditions.

Fortunately we have the technology!
if you go to
http://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp

and plug

`x := (6 # (sum largest 3 4d6));
if (2 <= (count 15 <= x)) &
   (3 <= (count 12 <= x)) &
   (4 <= (count 10 <= x))
then
    1
else
   0`

With a probability of 39%.

That is assuming I have the code correct.

Comment: +1 The probability is ${ 4346417192834375\over 10968475320188928
}\approx  0.3962644822$.